# Adding specific column value according to row value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe h3

```
Genotype Preference
Rice     1
Rice     2
Lr       3
Lr       3
th       4
th       7
```

I want the dataframe to look like

```
Genotype Preference Haplotype
Rice     1          1
Rice     2          1
Lr       3          2
Lr       3          2
th       4          0.5
th       7          0.5
```

That is I want to add a numerical variable to be added to the each type of genotype. I have around 100 observations for each type of genotype. I want to be able to add the numberical variable into a new column in a single line of code and ensure that 1 is added corresponding to rice, 2 to Lr and 0.5 to th.

I tried constructing the code with the `mutate`/`ifelse`:

`h3 %>% select(Genotype) %>% mutate(Type = ifelse (Genotype = c("Rice"), 1, Genotype))`

Other results which I looked up, provide solutions for adding a column with a calculated value from the previous columns but not specific values.

I have found this [dplyr mutate with conditional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/dplyr-mutate-with-conditional-values) and [Apply R-function to rows depending on value in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778174/apply-r-function-to-rows-depending-on-value-in-other-column) but dont know how to modify it for my code.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for testing equality. You've tried to assign within `ifelse` instead of testing equality

Comment: Thank you @camille how do I construct my code now then? because if I use == then I am getting a result which is only consisting of my genotype. I am pretty new to r.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But `ifelse(Genotype = c("Rice"), 1, Genotype))` should be `ifelse(Genotype == "Rice", 1, Genotype))`, if what you want is to replace "Rice" with 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Haplotype = ifelse(Genotype == "Rice",1,ifelse(Genotype == "Lr",2,0.5)))
```

Using `base`, you can do the same thing:

```r
df$Haplotype = ifelse(df$Genotype == "Rice",1,ifelse(df$Genotype == "Lr",2,0.5))
```

**Data**

```r
df = data.frame("Genotype" = c("Rice","Rice","Lr","Lr","Th","Th"),
                "Preference" = c(1,2,3,3,4,7))
```

Comment: @KeerthiKrutha, glad that it works for you. FYI, `ifelse` structure is 1st argument is the condition to be tested, 2nd argument is the output if the 1st argument is True, 3rd argument is the output if the 1st argument is False.